Можно ли получать осмысленный результат на промежуточный слоях нейросети?
Грубо говоря на входе в нейронку список команд, в средних слоях должна быть статистика (сколько пассов, угловых), а на выходе результат, сколько голов Можно ли делать такое промежуточное обучение, да так, чтобы последние слои не игнорировали логиты с первого? А тоже их учитывалли

Разделите на две нейросети: на первой получаете ваш промежуточный результат, на второй - окончательный
